# Make macros with random (but specific) output

Tags: macros, random

I try to find a way to make a

```
\newcommand
```

so that it has different outputs, that it chooses randomly.
In the best case the macro should also avoid word repetitions (something like, only choose this word if it hasnt been used for 50 words).

In this macro I want to group similar words, I use a lot in the document.
For example if I often write the same name, it should sometimes just print the family name and other times the full name.

**Edit** another example: the macro should print "the group" or "the group of people" or any different synonym, so that I just have one macro for this pool of words.

Comment: Interesting question ;-)

Comment: What do you want to achieve with it? What is the context? If you just need some text [`lipsum`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) can help. Some "rubbish" can be generated for example [here](http://thatsmathematics.com/mathgen/).

Comment: @Hackbard_C: Did you read the question???

Comment: @Hackbard_C no I want specific output, like I tried to explain in this sentence: For example if I often write the same name, it should sometimes just print the family name and other times the full name.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I did - but obviously i didn't get it.

Comment: varioref does something similar (but just alternates between two styles)

Comment: @Hackbard_C example: the makro should print "the group" or "the group of people" or any different synonym, so that I just have one makro for this pool of words.

Comment: The pool could be a list and the macro could loop to a random position in the loop and if its the same entry after less than 50 counts, loop again to find a better one. I'll try something

Comment: @ChristianHupfer that sounds right, and how do I accomplish that ;)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Take it, I have time.

Comment: @Benutzer193 Thanks for the explanation. Can this [random quote selector](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187011/31323) help?

Comment: @Hackbard_C I think it should be possible to do with datatool, I have to try. I don't know (yet) if it is possible to restrict the usage of the same word in a specific distance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can define the macro by specifying a relative frequency:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\input{random}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% alias \setrannum to an expl3 function
\cs_set_eq:NN \benutzer_set_rannum:Nnn \setrannum

\NewDocumentCommand{\newrandomcommand}{mm}
 {% #1 is the macro name, #2 is the data
  \cs_if_exist:cTF { #1 }
   {
    ERROR!
   }
   {
    \benutzer_new_random_command:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__benutzer_data_seq
\int_new:N \l__benutzer_random_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \benutzer_new_random_command:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__benutzer_data_seq { , } { #2 }
  \seq_new:c { g_benutzer_#1_data_seq }
  \benutzer_process_data:n { #1 }
  \cs_new_protected:cpn { #1 }
   {
    \benutzer_set_rannum:Nnn \l__benutzer_random_int { 1 }
     { \seq_count:c { g_benutzer_#1_data_seq } }
    \seq_item:cn { g_benutzer_#1_data_seq } { \l__benutzer_random_int }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \benutzer_process_data:n #1
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__benutzer_data_seq
   {
    \__benutzer_process_item:nw { #1 } ##1 // \q_stop
   }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \__benutzer_process_item:nw #1 #2 / #3 / #4 \q_stop
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nTF { #3 }
   {
    \__benutzer_add_item:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { 1 }
   }
   {
    \__benutzer_add_item:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__benutzer_add_item:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { #3 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:cn { g_benutzer_#1_data_seq } { #2 }
   }
 }

% this is just for testing
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{mm}
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { #2 } { #1\space }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% Fyodor will appear 10/61 times on average
% Michailovich will appear 1/61 times on average
% Dostoyevsky will appear 50/61 times on average
\newrandomcommand{fyodor}{Fyodor/10, Mikhailovich, Dostoyevsky/50}

\begin{document}

\raggedright
\test{\fyodor}{100}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution is really good. I specially like the option to set the average appearance of an word. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 12):

This is a preliminary version. The accounting of how much a word has been called so far is not done so far. I will update the solution...

Just define a word pool list with `\NewWordPool{poolname}{WordA,WordB,{SentenceA}}`

and say `\pickuprandomword{\poolname}`

The pool name is just like a macro name, but without `\`
character

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usepackage{ifthen}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%

\listgadd{\GroupWordsPools}{}%

\listgadd{\GroupWordsPoolsCount}{}%

\usepackage{forloop}%

\newcommand{\NewWordPool}[2]{%
\csxdef{#1}{}%
\forcsvlist{\listcsxadd{#1}}{#2}%
\csxdef{#1values}{}%
\forcsvlist{\listcsxadd{#1values}}{0}%
}%


\newcounter{loopcounter}%

\newcounter{randompos}%

\def\lastrandom{0}%

\newcommand{\pickuprandomword}[2][50]{%
\def\currentrandom{}%
%First counter the number of elements in the list
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
\stepcounter{randompos}%
}{}%
\dolistloop{#2}% 
\pgfmathrandominteger{\currentrandom}{1}{\number\value{randompos}}%
\whiledo{\lastrandom =\currentrandom}{%
\pgfmathrandominteger{\currentrandom}{1}{\number\value{randompos}}%
}%
\setcounter{randompos}{0}%
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
\stepcounter{randompos}%
\ifnumequal{\number\value{randompos}}{\currentrandom}{%
% Output the name
##1%
\listbreak%
}{}%
}%
\dolistloop{#2}%
\edef\lastrandom{\currentrandom}%
}%



\begin{document}

\NewWordPool{GroupWordsPool}{Hamlet,{Hamlet -- Prince of Denmark}, Shakespeare,{William Shakespeare}, Einstein,{Albert Einstein},Frodo, Bilbo, Gandalf,Aragorn,Galadriel,{Thorin Oakshield},Pippin,Elrond,Heisenberg,StackExchange}%


\forloop{loopcounter}{1}{\value{loopcounter} < 30}{%
\pickuprandomword{\GroupWordsPool}\par

}%
```

\end{document}

**Edit** I am still working on a better solution, but it needs time.

Comment: Also a really good answer, both ways do what I wanted to achieve! Thank you very much!

Comment: To the unknown downvoter: Leave a comment why you downvoted this answer

Comment: I hope it wasn't me. Some time ago, I accidentely voted one answer down, because I was on my mobile, but I immediately changed the vote to the desired upvote. I can't remember which answer it was and on which question.

Comment: @Benutzer193: Nope, it was a serial downvoter... he has left TeX.SX already or was kicked ;-)

Comment: That's good! :)

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

Better Version for the lua file, with different probabilies

```
n = math.random(1,6) 
if n == 6 then tex.sprint("foo1")
elseif n >= 4 then tex.sprint("foo2") 
else tex.sprint("foo3")
end
```

(example probabilites:
1/6 => foo1
1/3 => foo2
1/2 => foo3
)

Another easier solution with the compromise of fewer options (and only if using Lualatex):

set a new command:

```
\newcommand{\test}{\directlua{  dofile("test.lua")  }\xspace}
```

**test.lua:**

```
local test = { 'a','b'}
tex.sprint(test[math.random( #test )])
```

**a** and **b** need to be changed the desired text output (more words can be added of course)
and **test** can be changed to the desired name of the command.

---

I don't know if or how I can restrict the word repetition like in the other solutions or how to set the average appearance of a word.